# Invalid Swift Support. ... "doesn’t have the correct file type for this location" on App validation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I am trying to upload my app to iTunes Store. But when I try to do that I get the following message:

```
Invalid Swift Support. The file DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib, DeckBuilder.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib doesn’t have the correct file type for this location. Ensure you’re using the correct file, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.
```

I am getting crazy, I do not know what is the problem. I had XCode 9.2 (which is the latest version in the App Store; I updated it a few days ago), but I have deleted the XCode.app from /Applications in order to reinstall it from the AppStore. But I get the same error.

I have tried to upload a completely new app, a blank app, without any change, just like XCode creates it. And it gives me the same error.

I think there is something bad in my XCode installation, but I do not know what... Could you help me? Please? I have been trying a lot of things for 2 days.. I need to publish the app, I am loosing my time with this sh*tty error.

I am going to try to completely remove XCode, do you know what files should I remove?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this? I am currently experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I just tracked this down to accidentally trying to submit a build signed with an Ad Hoc profile to the App Store, rather than an App Store profile.